# Which way is faster when access a service in docker container?

Tags: service, docker

A service running in a docker container.

Assume the ip of the container is 172.18.0.4, and port forword by '-p 1234:8888'.

So access the service in host, which way is faster?

- 172.18.0.4:8888
- 127.0.0.1:1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to measure

I created a 157 MB file with the command `dd if=/dev/zero of=~/file bs=8k count=20000`. The command `netcat` will be used to transfer this file from the host into the container (with a published port). Details on how to transfer file using netcat are documented in the manpage.

#### Using the container IP address

```
user@host:~$ time nc -x 172.20.0.2 8888 < file
nc -x 172.20.0.2 8888 < file  0.00s user 0.07s system 38% cpu 0.178 total
user@host:~$ time nc -x 172.20.0.2 8888 < file
nc -x 172.20.0.2 8888 < file  0.00s user 0.05s system 36% cpu 0.152 total
user@host:~$ time nc -x 172.20.0.2 8888 < file
nc -x 172.20.0.2 8888 < file  0.00s user 0.06s system 35% cpu 0.169 total
```

#### Using the localhost IP address

```
user@host:~$ time nc -x 127.0.0.1 8888 < file
nc -x 127.0.0.1 8888 < file  0.00s user 0.06s system 33% cpu 0.180 total
user@host:~$ time nc -x 127.0.0.1 8888 < file
nc -x 127.0.0.1 8888 < file  0.00s user 0.06s system 38% cpu 0.158 total
user@host:~$ time nc -x 127.0.0.1 8888 < file
nc -x 127.0.0.1 8888 < file  0.00s user 0.06s system 40% cpu 0.137 total
```

#### Average

With the six transfers duration of the command, average durations are:
 - 0.166 using the container IP address.
 - 0.158 using the local host IP address.
There is 8 ms of difference.

#### Conclusion

**Disclaimer:** The file was not my `$HOMEDIR` but in `/tmp`, which is mapped into the memory. The reads were then faster. I am not sure when the `time` command stopped:
 - When the last TCP packet was sent?
 - When the last TCP packet was buffered?
 - When the last ACK was received? *I'll bet on this one*

In any ways the difference, of 8 ms, is, IMO, not a big deal. Even though 8 ms to load a page makes sometime a big difference, caching static file could offer a better result faster than this difference.

#### Answer

Using the local host IP address seems faster.

---

#### More tests ..

.. confirmed that localhost IP address with a small standard deviation (0.045 vs. 0.024). Note that the difference (9 ms) is about 5% of the average transfer duration (169 ms).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it would be the same.

An option that you can do to boost up the performance is configuring the container to use the host's network stack.

`docker run --net=host ...`

This guarantees best performance, however all ports in your container will be exposed to host.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-host

Comment: And it's unsecure.